How to resolve the "Unauthorized" error when using OAuth2-Proxy and Auth0 as the identity provider for my Kubernetes dashboard?
I have an issue with my Kubernetes dashboard that I want to authenticate to using OAuth2-Proxy and Auth0 as an identity provider. I have managed to deploy everything, and when I connect to the dashboard, I get redirected to the proxy and then to Auth0 where I authenticate successfully. After authentication, I get redirected back to the Kubernetes dashboard. However, in the dashboard itself, I can't see anything as I get an "Unauthorized" error. There are no errors in the OAuth2-Proxy pod or the Kubernetes dashboard pod other than: "Non-critical error occurred during resource retrieval: Unauthorized."
I have tried numerous configuration combinations that I found online, but nothing seems to be working. I would really appreciate any help with this issue.
Let me know if there are anymore information needed to solve this issue.
Thanks!
Here are my helm charts:
oauth2-proxy values:
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: oauth2
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: oauth2-proxy
      reconcileStrategy: ChartVersion
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: bitnami
        namespace: flux-system
      version: 5.0.0
  interval: 10m0s
  values:
    kubeVersion: "1.28.0"
    configuration:
      clientID: “XXX”
      cookieSecret: “XXX”
      oidcIssuerUrl: "https://xxx.auth0.com/"
      redirectUrl: "https://k8s-dashboard/oauth2/callback"
      whiteList: "k8s-dashboard"
    redis:
      enabled: false
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      hostname: "k8s-dashboard"
      path: /oauth2
      tls: true
      certManager: true
      existingSecretName: "oauth2-proxy-tls"
      ingressClassName: internal-nginx
      annotations:
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    extraEnvVars:
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: auth-0-secret
            key: clientsecret
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER
        value: "oidc"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAIN
        value: "k8s-dashboard"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_USER_HEADERS
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM
        value: "http://k8s-dashboard"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAIN
        value: "*"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SSL_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_INSECURE_OIDC_ALLOW_UNVERIFIED_EMAIL
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SSL_UPSTREAM_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_EMAIL_CLAIM
        value: "email"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_GROUPS_CLAIM
        value: groups
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_PROVIDER_BUTTON
        value: "true"
      - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
        value: "true"

kubernetes-dashboard-values:
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  values:
    extraArgs:
      ["--enable-insecure-login=true"]
    ingress:
      annotations:
        external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-dashboard
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "x-auth-request-user, x-auth-request-email, authorization"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://k8s-dashboard/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://k8s-dashboard/oauth2/auth"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          auth_request_set $token $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
          proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $token";
      hosts:
        - k8s-dashboard
      paths:
        - /
      tls:
        - secretName: k8s-dashboards-tls
          hosts:
            - k8s-dashboard

rbac.values:
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-clusterrolebinding
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  - kind: User
    name: "google-apps|XXX@XXX”
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - kind: User
    name: “XXX@XXX” # the email i see in the oauth2-proxy log which is the email i auth with
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

